# Reversing a string with a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, counting, reversing

got a very quick question to y'all as I'm relatively new to JavaScript. This task is actually from the freeCodeCamp course and it's about reversing a string as shown in the title. The question is, why do we include the -1 integer in the str.length line when we can just use the i-- to decrement the string count while reversing the actual string?

It kind of reminds me of what we do when using recursion for counting a set of numbers like (n-1), (n-2), (n-3) etc. Is it the same pattern going on? Or is it because of array's index counting since 0 is the first letter and not 1. Or something else? Thanks :)

```
function reverseString(str) {
  for (var reversedStr = "", i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedStr += str[i];  
  }   
  return reversedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i = str.length -1` sets the first index for `i` to look at. As strings and arrays are 0-indexed in most languages, valid indexes go from `0` to `length -1` and `str[length]` would actually be *after* the last character of the string.

Furthermore `i = str.length - 1` is only done *once* before the first iteration of the loop starts. `i--` is done on *every* iteration of the loop, but at the *end* of the current iteration.

Comment: Danke, makes sense now! I appreciate it sir!

Answer (score 0):

Length count is started from 1 and index count is started from 0. For `"lorem"`(`let str="lorem"`) , its length is 5 and but the index of its last character is 4. So if we donot subtract -1 from str.length , in first iteration  we will end up with `str[5]` , which donot exist and will return `undefined` . Its all counting from  0 vs counting from 1.

Comment: Thank you! That lorem example made it clear for me. Since the loop continues to iterate until it reaches its desired statement, it makes sense. Thanks!